# Why does Rails only name some of my routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Here's my routes file

```
Dumb::Application.routes.draw do

  # an auto-named route
  get '/a/b',            to: 'a#b'

  # apparently not auto-named???
  get '/a/z/:something', to: 'a#z'

end
```

Here's output of `rake routes`

```
a_b GET /a/b(.:format)            a#b
    GET /a/z/:something(.:format) a#z
```

Wow that sucks! At least for consistency's sake. If I change the `a#z` route to

```
get '/a/z/:something', to: 'a#z', as: "a_z"
```

`rake routes` will display

```
a_b GET /a/b(.:format)            a#b
a_z GET /a/z/:something(.:format) a#z
```

Ok that's good, but having to name the route like that is annoying.

Is this the only solution?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the routing table only assigns names automatically when the route is simple enough for that to work. Adding parameters might confuse it.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that Rails can't assign a name to your route because it does not understand it. Usually, you will want to write your route as such :

```
/a/:id/b/:id  # instead of /a/b/:id which Rails does not understand.
```

Rails maps `a` to a controller with a model instance with id `:id` and `b` to another controller with another model instance with id `:id`.

`/a/b/:id` does not refer to anything in terms of Rails convention.

Getting `GET /a/b` named to `a_b` was just a guess Rails made, but it can't work out `GET /a/z/:something`. What would it be? `a_z_something`?